# URL not catched RouteConfig ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a route like this

```
name: "XXXXX",
url: "page/{label}-{id},
defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Page", action = "Results",
        label= UrlParameter.Optional, id= UrlParameter.Optional
    },
```

when I call /page/white-1, it is OK
I want also be able to catch the URL /page/-1 (I have old URL like this and I want to redirect them)... but this URL /page/-1 is not catched and I have a 404.

But why it is not catched whereas I indicate the parameter as optional ? How can I catch it ?

Comment: Your need the additional route as per Anthony Shaw's answer because you can only have the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional` (other wise there is no way of matching up which parameter your providing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a second route that starts with a hyphen and then redirect to the new route with the proper label.

```
name: "XXXXX1",
url: "page/-{id},
defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Page", action = "OldResults",
        id= UrlParameter.Optional
    },
```

Then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult OldResults(int id) {
  //goto database get item by id 
  var item = db.getItem(id);
  return RedirectToAction("Results", new {id = id, label = item.label});
}
```